# Fit buttons and photos as the Game unity to the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my buttons and photos to have the same scale as game inspector . I want them to show on the mobile screen at the same size , but when I transfer the game to the phone with Xcode , it has other sizes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCDLt.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjMsI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will see Canvas Scaler component on canvas gameobject , set its **UI Scale Mode** to **Scale With Screen Size**. With this scale mode you can specify a resolution to use as reference. And it will make UI to stretch on large screen and shrinks on smaller screens.

For more information visit : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html